# How to bind values from Api to Angular form

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, angular-forms

I've created a angular form which sends values to webapi and prints the received value below the form on Submit.

Try.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSubmit()" class="mb-3"> 
  <!-- <form class="mb-3"> -->
    <div class="mb-3" class="row">
        <label for="bike" class="form-label fw-bold">Bike:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bike" formControlName="bike" placeholder="Enter your Bike name">
      </div> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Submit</button>
  </form> 
<br>
  <br>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered" role="grid">
    <thead class="bg-primary">
      <tr>
        <th>Bike Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let name of names">
        <td>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name.bike" name="bike">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

    </div>
  
</div>
```

Try.component.ts:

```
export class TryComponent {
  names: any[] = [];
  form: FormGroup;
 
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private namesService: NamesService) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      bike: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
    });
    this.namesService.getBikes();
  }
  Reset(){
    this.form.reset();
  }
  onSubmit() {
    this.form.controls['bike'].markAsTouched();
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const data={
        ...this.form.value,
        }
    console.log(data);                 
    this.namesService.addBike(data).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.namesService.getBikes().subscribe(names => {
        this.names = names;
        console.log(this.names);
        console.log("success");
      });
    });
  }
}
}
```

Names.service.ts:

```
export class NamesService {
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addBike(nameData : any): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post<any[]>('https://localhost:7006/api/Names/submit-form',nameData);
  }
  getBikes(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('https://localhost:7006/api/Names/get-form-data');
  }

}
```

The issue is not with the API, because I'm able to print the entered values as an array on the console (Works fine when tested with swagger).Even after importing the necessary modules I'm not able to bind the value and display it below the form. I guess the problem lies with the Array not being updated with the received values in front-end or the way I bind.

Can someone tell me where did I went wrong.

Comment: You do  this.namesService.getBikes(); and that is it? You should assign the returned service values to the form controls... have something like  bike: [x.bike, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]

Comment: @DA  doesn't that already be assigned to the array after response from api?

Comment: nope. Where is the assign? and what array? In onSubmit u have the assignment ... this.namesService.getBikes().subscribe(names => {
        this.names = names;